# Can I vertically align inline blocks based on their children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

To illustrate this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}

.vm {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col ib vm">
    <div>aaa<br>a</div>
    <div>b<br><br>b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col ib vm">
    <div>a<br><br><br><br>a</div>
    <div>b<br><br>bbbbbbbbbb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we have two inline blocks (i.e. `.col`), and they're vertically aligned at the middle. The question is:

**Can I make the `.col`s vertically aligned by the middle of the inner children?** (For example, the children containing "b".)

Or do I have to use JavaScript to calculate the position and apply `transform`?

As each `.col` may contain multiple children and I have many such `.col`s, implementation without JavaScript would be great.

Any solutions with grid, or flex, layout are OK.

The desired result is like the following image:

[image: two .cols are vertically alligned by their second children]

The `.col`s should be vertically moved such that the middle of their second children (regardless of the middle of the two `.col`s) are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with only CSS. If you need exactly this behavior the best thing you can do is probably to calculate needed margin-top for appropriate column using JavaScript. With correct margin second rows will appear as vertically centered.

If overlapping behavior can be sacrificed, you can place content in rows instead of columns and vertically center contents of second row.
[image: illustration]